# Error after trying build Android test app

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, dotnet-sdk

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The imported project "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk. FirstApp.Android    D:\projects\vs\Mobile\FirstApp\FirstApp\FirstApp\FirstApp.csproj
```

Error which shows up after building (device realme RMX3363, Android 13.0)

I nothing try's 'cause idk what I can do.

Comment: What type of project are you creating? Xamarin or MAUI? Have you tried reinstalling VS to see if the error exists?